# RCV into matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have data that looks like this

```
Row_idx    Column_idx    Value
AA         AA            1
AA         BB            2
AA         CC            3
BB         BB            1
BB         CC            4
CC         CC            1

df=pd.DataFrame({'Row_idx':['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','CC'],'Column_idx':['AA','BB','CC','BB','CC','CC'],'Value':[1,2,3,1,4,1]})
```

which represents the upper half of a covariance matrix

```
    AA    BB    CC
AA  1     2     3
BB        1     4
CC              1
```

How can I most efficiently get my data into a complete matrix again.
The data gets read into a dataframe from a file and has a few hundred thousand rows, therefore I would like to avoid using some nested looping approach.

Eventually I need this as a np.array

```
1    2    3
2    1    4
3    4    1
```

I was thinking about using numpy's triu package to complete the matrix but how do I get it quickly from RCV dataframe into properly row and column indexed dataframe?

Comment: That `Value` holds the upper triangular elements of the desired output array, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df

  Column_idx Row_idx  Value
0         AA      AA      1
1         BB      AA      2
2         CC      AA      3
3         BB      BB      1
4         CC      BB      4
5         CC      CC      1
```

Call [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`np.fmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html#numpy.fmax):

```
x = df.pivot('Row_idx', 'Column_idx', 'Value').values
np.fmax(x, x.T)

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  1.]])
```

*In this case*, you can also do ([thanks, B. M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959674/rcv-into-matrix/46959838?noredirect=1#comment80867157_46959838)):

```
x = df.pivot(*df.columns)
```

And end up with the same result, since you're dealing with a triangular matrix.

Comment: Or just `df.pivot(*df.columns)` .

Comment: @B.M. Yes, that's an interesting alternative that would work in this particular instance, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `Value` column holds are the upper triangular elements. So, to create the full matrix/array, we can use some masking -

```
def full_tri(v): # v is array holding values to be assigned into o/p
    n = int(np.sqrt(len(v)*2)) # size of squared output array
    out = np.empty((n,n),dtype=v.dtype)
    r = np.arange(n)
    m = r[:,None] <= r
    out[m] = v
    out.T[m] = v
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [757]: df
Out[757]: 
  Column_idx Row_idx  Value
0         AA      AA      1
1         BB      AA      2
2         CC      AA      3
3         BB      BB      1
4         CC      BB      4
5         CC      CC      1

In [758]: full_tri(df.Value.values)
Out[758]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's soln
def pivot_fmax(df):
    x = df.pivot('Row_idx', 'Column_idx', 'Value').values
    return np.fmax(x, x.T)

# @B. M.'s soln
def pivot_fillna(df):
    M=df.pivot(*df.columns)
    M.fillna(M.T,inplace=True)
    return M.values
```

Timings on bigger datasets -

```
In [791]: N = 1000 # size of testing dataset
     ...: r,c = np.triu_indices(N)
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[r,c,np.random.randint(11,99,(len(r)))])
     ...: df.columns = [['Row_idx', 'Column_idx', 'Value']]
     ...: 

In [792]: %timeit pivot_fmax(df)
     ...: %timeit pivot_fillna(df)
     ...: %timeit full_tri(df.Value.values)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 89.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 96.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.19 ms per loop

In [793]: N = 2000 # size of testing dataset
     ...: r,c = np.triu_indices(N)
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[r,c,np.random.randint(11,99,(len(r)))])
     ...: df.columns = [['Row_idx', 'Column_idx', 'Value']]
     ...: 

In [794]: %timeit pivot_fmax(df)
     ...: %timeit pivot_fillna(df)
     ...: %timeit full_tri(df.Value.values)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 412 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 425 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the DataFrame, just do:

```
M=df.pivot(*df.columns)
M.fillna(M.T,inplace=True)

# Column_idx   AA   BB   CC
# Row_idx                  
# AA          1.0  2.0  3.0
# BB          2.0  1.0  4.0
# CC          3.0  4.0  1.0
```